# Identification of 6-pin chip marked W134H?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification, components

Would like to ask for help in the identification of 6-pin chip marked: W134H  (it's not a clock signal generator)

I think it conditions very low voltage (5mv-200mv) analog voltage inputs for a chip marked AX4A which is an LMH6611 single supply rail-to-rail Amplifier.

Thank you for any help!  (uploaded a better photo)

https://ibb.co/4TnsGJM

https://ibb.co/xLKkHqm

Comment: What function does this pcb serve? Input/outputs? Is it a mini jack input on the left side?

Comment: Yes, it's a mini-audio jack.  It has a two-channel audio input jack and the PCB measures the time difference between the two analog input signals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a TVS diode array made by [WURTH ELEKTRONIK](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1671179.pdf)

its position near an audio jack, makes it likely to be that.

Comment: Thank you very much!  It certainly makes sense. I partly traced the circuit back to the jack and both inputs of the stereo jack connect directly to the first two opposing pins.  Most likely to protect the rest of the circuit from a surge, static, etc...